# Display two fields from different databases

Tags: asp.net

I am creating a simple Leave Management application for which User Management is required.

For this I used ASP.NET Configuration tool and created roles, users and permissions. A `ASPNETDB.mdf` database was generated under `App_Code`. Next I created few .aspx pages like `login.aspx`, `register.aspx`, `changepassword.aspx`, `displayinfo.aspx`, etc. I placed the required Login controls in each page. In `displayinfo.aspx` (after the user login.aspx) I placed a `LoginName` control which displays a message like "Welcome LoginNameControl(UserName)". Next I created another database called "LMS" for maintaining Employees Leave Information which has tables like employee, dept, LeaveType, LeavePolicy, etc.

Now my question is when a user authenticates, how do I display the `EmployeeID` from the `Employee` table in `display.aspx` along with the `UserName` which has no relation with the `ASPNETDB.mdf` database?

I guess this can be achieved with datarelation concept of a `DataSet`, but I have no idea how to do it. Can anyone please provide me clear guidelines with proper code? I am not sure when to use ASP.NET Configuration tool and whether it's the right choice in this case.

Answer (score 0):

If both of the databases are on the same instance you could do something like this:

select database1.table1.column1 , database2.table2.column2

If not than you should have some DAL and write the code for it using the DAL's conventions

Answer (score 0):

> Now my question is when user login how
>   to display the EmployeeID of Employee
>   table in display.aspx along with the
>   UserName which has no relation with
>   “ASPNETDB.mdf” database.

You don't have to create a separate aspnetdb.mdf , what you can do is just simply run the asp_regsql command against your own database, then all the tables/views/stored procedures will b e created for you to use the build-in aspnet security/membership feature. Then you can easily create a foreign key relationship between different tables ( Your own table and aspnet table).

HTH.